# Is there such a thing as a compound noun?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to decide if I can use this phrase to designate a non-profit organization in Africa:
"Living Water Team, Nigeria and Uganda Villages"

OR does it need to say:
"Living Water Team, Nigerian and Ugandan Villages"

Thank you.

Comment: You are trying to characterize an entity called "Living Water Team" that operates in villages in Nigeria and Uganda, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I am needing to use it in a title before the description of what they do.

Comment: I think I may be referring to a noun adjunct as I research this.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

To me, the slight advantage of "Nigerian and Ugandan Villages" over "Nigeria and Uganda Villages" is that it unmistakably connects the villages to Nigeria as well as to Uganda. That is, a reader may interpret "Nigeria and Uganda Villages" as meaning either

> (Nigeria) + (Uganda Villages)

or as

> (Nigeria + Uganda) Villages

but the only plausible reading of "Nigerian and Ugandan Villages" is

> (Nigerian + Ugandan) Villages

Grammatically there is nothing wrong with either formulation, but in my view "Nigerian and Ugandan Villages" avoids any ambiguity as to which words modify "Villages," and therefore is marginally less susceptible to misreading.